# How to define a symbolic link that I can use in every directory

Tags: bash, symlink

Is it possible to set a symbolic link so that I can use `project` to point the directory `home/me/project`, e. g.? This should be independent of the location in the file system.

I'd like to use commands like `cd project`, `nano project/file1.tex` and so on.

Do I have to write a symbolic link to all of my directories?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most shells have a `CDPATH` variable that `cd` can lookup for directories to  change to in the same way that executables are searched in `$PATH`.

So if you add your symlinks in a `~/projects` directory and do `CDPATH=~/projects`, you'll be able to do `cd foo` to go in `~/projects/foo`

With `zsh`, if `$var` contains a path you can do `cd ~var` to `cd` to that path. The useful part of that is when your prompt has `%~` which then reflects it in your prompt:

```
$ proj1=/usr/local proj2=/etc/apache2
$ PS1='%~$ '
$ cd ~proj1
~proj1$ cd ~proj2/sites-enabled
~proj2/sites-enabled$
```

With `setopt cdablevars`, you can also do `cd proj1` instead of `cd ~proj1`.

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to use variables instead of symbolic links, e.g.

```
export project=/home/me/project
```

then

```
cd $project
```

or

```
vim $project/file
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by peterph, you can also combine these (including predefined variables), e.g.

```
export project=$HOME/project
```

Comment: Or even better `project=$HOME/project`...

Comment: @peterph, or even simpler `~/project`.

Comment: With `zsh`, you can also do `setopt cdablevars` and then `cd project`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: I think that's a good point - though as it's specific to `zsh` perhaps you could add that as a separate answer?